# How to write If condition where the value is character data

Tags: r

I have a dataframe "weather" where i have weekday information (Monday to sunday). I have to mutate a new column dummy weekday where it's = 1 if it is Saturday or Sunday, and = 0 otherwise. this is what I write

```
for (i in 1:nrow(weather)) {
  if (weather$weekday[i] == "Saturday" || weather$weekday[i] == "Sunday") {
    weather$weekend_dummy = 1
  } else {
    weather$weekend_dummy = 0
  }
}
```

but it has this error : Error in if (weather$weekday[i] == "Saturday" || weather$weekday[i] ==  :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and in particular note that all inputs should be provided using `dput `so that anyone can just copy the code in the question and paste it into their session to run it.  As presented currently only you can run it as the input is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I have my local R on German, sorry for that. But should be easy to adapt as the days sound very similar :-)

**Base R solution:**

```
your_df$weekend_dummy = ifelse(your_df$wday == "Samstag" | your_df$wday == "Sonntag", 1, 0)
```

**data.table solution:**

```
library(data.table)
    
dt = data.table(your_df)
dt[, weekend_dummy:=ifelse(wday == "Samstag" | wday == "Sonntag", 1, 0)]
```

**Output:**

```
> dt
         wday weekend_dummy
1:     Montag             0
2:   Dienstag             0
3:   Mittwoch             0
4: Donnerstag             0
5:    Freitag             0
6:    Samstag             1
7:    Sonntag             1
```

In most cases you don't need loops in R, because R is much faster when calculating vector based.

PS, please provide next time some data like:

```
your_df = data.frame(wday=weekdays(as.Date(c("2021-01-04", "2021-01-05", "2021-01-06", "2021-01-07", "2021-01-08", "2021-01-09", "2021-01-10"))))
```

Comment: thank you so so much